# Vertical Tabs in Front End (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I am trying to use Vertical Tabs on the front end of my site.

Normally, I would just add a jQuery plug-in to my theme. However, vertical tabs are built into Drupal 7, so it seems silly to use a plugin, when the functionality already exists.

I'm just not sure how to call the built-in vertical tabs.

[Dan Silver's blog has an excellent tutorial](http://dansilvercentral.com/jquery-ui-tabs-drupal-7-tutorial) on how to call the built-in tabs. However, his tutorial is for horizontal tabs. I am not sure how to convert them to vertical ones.

I would appreciate if anyone could give me some hints.

(P.S. I am aware that modules exist to do this. However, for my purposes it seems overkill to use a module when I can achieve it with a few simple lines of theming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module will provide you some custom code to implement this, have a look at the [API documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/vertical_tabs_example--vertical_tabs_example.module/function/vertical_tabs_example_form_alter/7) which add a vertical tab to the node form.

The only restriction I can think of is that this code is for forms so if you want to theme a node output you should use jQUery UI tabs. The tutorial you linked seems fine, but you'll need to change a little its CSS classes in order to output vertical tabs, compare its code tho this [demo](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/tabs/vertical.html).

Comment: Does this mean that the vertical/horizontal aspect is controlled fully by CSS? (I.e. the Jquery remains the same regardless if you want a horizontal or vertical menu?)

Comment: That is correct, compare the source code of the [default tabs implementation](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/tabs/default.html) vs [the vertical one](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/tabs/vertical.html), there's only a few CSS lines that differ for the class `.ui-tabs-vertical`.